# How to get all bounds from boost::rtree

Tags: c++, boost, bounds, boost-geometry, r-tree

I have a built boost rtree:

```
using CBGPoint3d    = boost::geometry::model::point<float, 3, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>;
using CBGBox3D      = boost::geometry::model::box<CBGPoint3d>;
using CBGTreeItem   = std::pair<CBGBox3D, CEntityLoaderBase*>;

boost::geometry::index::rtree<CBGTreeItem, boost::geometry::index::dynamic_rstar> m_tree;
```

I can iterate through leaf nodes:

```
for (auto const& v : m_tree)
   //do something
```

I can get root bounds:

```
m_tree.bounds();
```

But how can I get other level bounds ? There is no bounds iterator....

Comment: What gives you the impression that you can look at the implementation details? I don't see that in any part of the documented interface. `rtree` merely indexes your stuff, assuming how it does so should not interest you.

Comment: The relevant implementation detail seems to be `detail::rtree::visitors::children_box` and in order to use it you require friend access to `member_holder m_members`. Also, none of this is documented let alone supported.

Comment: @sehe "rtree merely indexes your stuff, assuming how it does so should not interest you.", but I need info about grouping :( Volumes overlap.

Comment: "Volumes overlap" -> multi-value queries. "I need to know about grouping" - if by that you meant the hierarchy in which the index tree is built, then (a) this is not stable (varies with insertion order) (b) depends on the parameters. None of those are documented.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a part of the official interface but it is possible to traverse the R-tree manually. You have to implement your own node visitor and use `bgi::detail::rtree::utilities::view<Rtree>` to apply it to the root node. Have a look at the utilities in this directory:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities

in particular the one checking correctness of bounding boxes in the hierarchy:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/are_boxes_ok.hpp

and the one gathering statistics about the internal structure of the R-tree:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/statistics.hpp